# How to speed up QAction::setIcon

Tags: c++, qt, optimization, qtwidgets

With the system I have currently, I have to run `QAction::setIcon` around thirty times every time a new file is loaded. This is for populating an open with menu.

Each call of `setIcon` is around 25ms, leading to an extremely annoying half-second delay when switching files.

I have tried moving the menu population to another thread, which works well, but I get `QObject::startTimer: Timers cannot be started from another thread` in the console, as QWidgets aren't meant to be used in any thread but the GUI thread.

I believe the delay to be because the icon is copied each call, as `QAction` stores the `QIcon` as a value.

The relevant line is [here](https://github.com/jurplel/qView/blob/eee6b693e3694876950bada0d47756803b2aed14/src/mainwindow.cpp#L382). Interestingly, in another place in my program, setIcon is called, and it is slow only one time, somehow being cached in every subsequent call ([here](https://github.com/jurplel/qView/blob/eee6b693e3694876950bada0d47756803b2aed14/src/actionmanager.cpp#L453)).

Any suggestions? I have tried everything I can think of.

Comment: Can you create and store your actions during your application startup?

Comment: The actions are created and stored during application startup but the icons need to be changed based on what open with handlers are available.

Answer (score 0):

Look into [QPixmapCache](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpixmapcache.html) and store your icon in a pixmap instead. Constructing a `QIcon` from a `QPixmap` is very straightforward. Look into this [QIcon constructor](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qicon.html#QIcon-1). You may just put the `QPixmap` in there, since the constructor is implicit anyway. This should speed things up.